# Excel VBA - Date Format Conversion

Tags: date, excel, date-formatting, vba

I have come across a challenging task which I am not able to solve using many workarounds.

In one column I have dates, the date can be in following three formats:

> 1) Simple dd/mm/yy
>
> 2) dd/mm/yy but may have words "before,after or about" around it. Any
>   one of it and we just need to delete those words in this case.
>
> 3) Date in a numeric format. A long decimal values like 1382923.2323
>   but actually I can get a date from it after conversion.

**The file is uploaded here. [Date_format_macro_link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvQXNzWFhta0ZqUWs/edit?usp=sharing)**

I wrote the following code but it's giving wrong results.

```
Sub FormatDates_Mine()
    ManualSheet.Activate
    ManualSheet.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
    ManualSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    ManualSheet.Cells.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    lastRow = ManualSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Col = "A"
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Cells(i, Col) = Trim(Replace(Cells(i, Col), vbLf, "", 1, , vbTextCompare))

        If InStr(1, Cells(i, Col), "about", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, Col) = Trim(Replace(Cells(i, Col), "about", "", 1, , vbTextCompare))
            Cells(i, Col).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 151, 149)
        End If

        If InStr(1, Cells(i, Col), "after", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, Col) = Trim(Replace(Cells(i, Col), "after", "", 1, , vbTextCompare))
            Cells(i, Col).Interior.Color = RGB(228, 109, 10)
        End If

        If InStr(1, Cells(i, Col), "before", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, Col) = Trim(Replace(Cells(i, Col), "before", "", 1, , vbTextCompare))
            Cells(i, Col).Interior.Color = RGB(228, 109, 10)
        End If

        DateParts = Split(Cells(i, Col), "/", , vbTextCompare)

        Cells(i, Col) = Format(Cells(i, Col), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Next i

    Range("D:E").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

**The file is uploaded here. [Date_format_macro_link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvQXNzWFhta0ZqUWs/edit?usp=sharing)**

Please help!

Comment: You have mentioned how your data looks like but you haven't mentioned what do you want to do with it. For example what happens to `About 21/05/09` ? From your code it looks like you want to remove all unwanted chars and turn it into a date?

Comment: There are some values inside your data which doesn't meet `data type` criteria. To omit that problem you could use something like `If IsDate(Cells(i, Col)) Then` before you set `.Format` property. For other problems see @SiddharthRout comment...

Comment: I reckon you could do that with just a worksheet formula...and set the colour using Conditional formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have not added any error handling. I am assuming that you will not be deviating for the existing format of your data. If the format changes then you WILL have to introduce error handling.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MyAr() As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lRow)

        With rng
            '~~> Replace "After " in the entire column
            .Replace What:="After ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

            DoEvents

            '~~> Replace "About " in the entire column
            .Replace What:="About ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End With

        For i = 2 To lRow
            '~~> Remove the End Spaces
            .Range("A" & i).Value = Sid_SpecialAlt160(.Range("A" & i).Value)

            '~~> Remove time after the space
            If InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, " ") Then _
            .Range("A" & i).Formula = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, " ")(0)

            '~~> Convert date like text  to date
            .Range("A" & i).Formula = DateSerial(Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, "/")(2), _
                                                 Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, "/")(1), _
                                                 Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, "/")(0))
        Next i

    End With
End Sub

Public Function Sid_SpecialAlt160(s As String)
    Dim counter As Long

    If Len(s) > 0 Then
        counter = Len(s)
        While VBA.Mid(s, counter, 1) = " "
            counter = counter - 1
        Wend
        Sid_SpecialAlt160 = VBA.Mid(s, 1, counter)
    Else
        Sid_SpecialAlt160 = s
    End If
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: +1 for **Sid_SpecialAlt160** (and screenshots) and it works, but couldn't this be solved using worksheet formulas?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Sorry but I don't this is what I want. I want each and every date to be converted in mm/dd/yy. If you see cell A1, before it was dd/m/yyyy and after it is dd/mm/yy. You got my point? Thanks and please give it a try again

Comment: @Tejas: If you want it as `mm/dd/yy` then simply change the line `.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` in my above code to `.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"`. I chose "dd/mm/yyyy" because you did the same in your code in your question ;)