# Date field exported as string in XLS

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

For internationalization purpose, as of today, we get the user locale from a table and use it in the parameter `$P{Locale}`. So `$P{Locale}` will have values such as `'en-IN'`, `'de-DE'` etc.

Inside the date field I put the below code

`$V{SowingDate1} != null ? DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale($P{Locale}.split("-")[0], $P{Locale}.split("-")[1])).format(DateUtils.addMinutes($V{SowingDate1},$P{UtcOffSet})) : null`

And I get the date as expected and the datatype of the field is `java.sql.Timestamp`

However, when I export to xls, the same field is taken as a string and I am unable to calculate any computation.

This does not work either - `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>`

Any ideas on this would be of great help

Comment: What is your question? How to export Date value as cell of Date type or what?

Comment: My question is the date field must be exported as date in xls. I have written the java code to display dates according to the user locale (for example, india - 11/11/1986, finnish - 11.11.1986). And I have the data type of the cell as timestamp. But when exported to excel gets converted to a string

Comment: `My question is the date field must be exported as date in xls` - it depends on you (I don't know what task you are solving). If the cell (in xls) of Date type it is a Excel issue how to show value with Locale settings. If the cell of String type and has a valid format (depends on Locale) you can try Excel features to convert data (for example, [Converting a string to a date in a cell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16089263/876298))

Comment: This is the date format in that comes out of Jasper dd/mm/yyyy. This gets exported as string. I am unable to understand why this is happening

Comment: I don't really understand what you are up to, but pass the Date in the textField and use patterns on field, this way you will have correct result in excel, hence to excel a Date object is passed.

Comment: I can set the date pattern. But some countries have specific patterns such as dd.mm.yyyy and some other countries as dd/mm/yyyy. How do I achieve this?